# definição de Agente da passiva inclui a preposição?

Tags: sintaxe, voz-passiva

Em um concurso que fiz, a questão foi a seguinte:

> Em: "O exemplo de sucesso nesse caso já foi concluído pelos advogados…", marque a opção que apresenta a função sintática do termo "pelos advogados":
>
> a) adjunto adnominal
> b) agente da passiva
> c) adjunto adverbial
> d) objeto direto

O gabarito preliminar deu como certa a alternativa *b*, e eu havia marcado a letra *a*.

Eu interpus recurso com o seguinte embasamento abaixo:

---

> O termo *pelos advogados* representa dentro do contexto frásico a estrutura preposição + agente da passiva.
>
> Conforme a professora Flávia Neves (ver https://www.normaculta.com.br/agente-da-passiva/) A construção de uma frase na *voz passiva analitica* é: SUJEITO  PACIENTE + (VERBO AUXILIAR + PARTICÍPIO) + PREPOSIÇÃO + AGENTE DA PASSIVA.
>
> Neste caso temos a preposição *pelo* + o nome *advogados*, sendo que, o agente da passiva é o nome, e nunca a preposição + o nome.
>
> Ou seja, *advogados* seria o agente da passiva.
>
> Mas o gabarito erra ao afirmar que o agente da passiva é representado por preposição + o nome.
>
> Em https://www.normaculta.com.br/agente-da-passiva/ inclusive temos um exemplo de frase semelhante ao apresentado na questão 16:
>
> O esboço do edifício foi desenhado pelo arquiteto.
>
> Aqui a professora Flávia afirma que o agente da passiva é o termo *o arquiteto* e não *pelo arquiteto*.
>
> Alem disso:
>
> No exemplo dado, a expressão *pelos advogados* exerce a função sintática de objeto preposicionado. A preposição *por* está relacionando o sujeito *exemplo de sucesso* com o objeto *advogados*, indicando que o sucesso foi concluído por meio das ações ou trabalho dos advogados. Em outras palavras, a preposição *por* estabelece uma relação de causa ou meio, indicando que os advogados foram os responsáveis pela conclusão do exemplo de sucesso.

---

Eu apenas queria saber o quê realmente vale: vale dizer que o agente da passiva é formado por "preposição + agente da passiva"? :(

Comment: Eu lavo os pratos. Os pratos são lavados por mim. Agente da passiva, igualzinho à sua frase.  Claro, a preposição + o agente da passiva. E claro, a agente da passiva não é a preposição.

Comment: correção: o agente. :)

Comment: Veja: https://www.todamateria.com.br/agente-da-passiva/ Agente da Passiva é o termo que indica quem ou o que executa a ação de um verbo na voz passiva. **Esse termo vem sempre depois de preposição**.

Answer (score 0):

O agente da passiva no português deve sempre ser um sintagma preposicional, isto é, sempre tem de ter uma preposição. Pode-se dizer sem problemas que tudo desde a preposição é o agente, veja, por exemplo, o exemplo do objeto indireto

> Dei o livro ao João

Dizemos comumente que "ao João" é o objeto indireto e, em praticamente todos os dialetos, é um sintagma preposicional também.

Não é uma questão muito relevante em termos de análise, eu diria, não sei que implicações isso poderiar ter, se um dia achar algo mais editarei esta resposta! Mas foi uma boa pergunta!

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146611/discussion-on-answer-by-ergative-man-definicao-de-agente-da-passiva-inclui-a-pre); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.